# Access Fortran derived type's component by dynamic name

Tags: string, class, properties, fortran

Is there a way in Fortran to access a derived type's component when presented with a string? I've done this before using Matlab with structs, but I don't know if there is any way to do this in fortran.

For example, with:

```
  module class_mod
  implicit none

  private

  public :: obj,get_prop

  type obj
    private
    integer :: i
  end type

  contains

  function get_prop(A,p) result(R)
    implicit none
    type(obj),intent(in) :: A
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: p
    integer :: R
    R = A%(p)
  end function

  end module

  program main
  use class_mod
  implicit none

  type(obj) :: A
  integer :: i
  A%i = 5
  i = get_prop(A,'i')
  write(*,*) 'i = ',i

  end module
```

I would expect that the printed value is 5.

Comment: You mean to access the component which has name given by a string?  You can't do this, much as you [can't with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9536346/3157076).

Comment: Ok, I figured it may not be possible. Thanks @francescalus.