# Call a subroutine from string with its name in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Assume I have subroutine with the name 'f1' and a variable which contains its name.
Hence, something like

```
    subroutine f1(input1, ..., inputN)
       does something
    end subroutine f1

    subroutine_name = "f1"
```

I would like to call this subroutine with the help of `subroutine_name`.
I.e. (naivly) something like:

```
   subroutine_name(input1, ..., inputN)
```

Is something like that possible in fortran?
**Can I write a subroutine that checks if a subroutine with a certain name exists and if so passes some parameters along to it?**

Comment: No, at least not simply and portably. There are duplicates of this, you might google for them.

Comment: You can have pointers to subroutines (see http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/proc_component_example) , and use those pointers to select which subroutine to call.   Perhaps that could be used to solve your problem?

Comment: @M.S.B. I would run into the same problem where I would have to compare strings to pointer names, wouldn't I?
To give some context:
I have a configuration file (i.e. yaml) where a set of variables are defined in combination with a set of subroutine names and their input parameters. I would like to define and init the corresponding variables (I think thats doable) and apply the subroutines.

Comment: I found a fortran-yaml [script][1] that reads key-value pairs.
If this is possible I should be able to write a script that creates pointers with the name of the subroutine and then make them point to the subroutine (i.e. with a macro.).
Does something like this have a name in fortran? There must be examples that use something like this.

  [1]: https://github.com/fabm-model/fabm/blob/c19cdb13cc63b29dbeccd518209bb23554872777/src/yaml/yaml.F90

Comment: @465b In principle, you could use a pre-processor to do that but, most likely, you do not want to go that route. Regarding *I would like to define and init the corresponding variables and apply the subroutines.*, doesn't it work for you to create a routing procedure that decides, based on the input data, which procedures to call? Something like `if (proc_name == 'f1') call f1(args)` or `if (proc_name == 'f1') f => f1`

Comment: @PetrH I am porting code, and would like to keep it as close to the source as possible. However, I think you are right (with both the pre-processer comment as well as the routing procedure).

Comment: This is the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536346/determine-variable-names-dynamically-according-to-a-string-in-fortran I am even inclined to close as a duplicate, but I must admit one is about data and one about procedures. When porting from a dynamic language you cannot expect to keep structure when it uses features that are not available in traditional languages.