# How to look up an object by name in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a quick question for some Fortran programmer more expert than me.

I would like know if is there any container or method to look up an object by "name". Ideally, I am thinking at some type of table like this:

"myObj1": pointer to obj1
"myObj2": pointer to obj2
"myObj3": pointer to obj3

My plan is to create a sort of object registry whcih will be quite good for my code development. Any hint anybody?

Many thanks as always

Comment: Not sure thaht is 100% what I am after. I was thinking to something like an hash table with associate a pointer to a name, but not sure this is possible.

Comment: Please [edit] into your question why the linked question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536446/3157076) doesn't help in creating a hash table (for example). Example code of how you would like to use whatever structure is possible would also help. (Note that the overall answer of "there's no reflection in Fortran" applies.)

Comment: Thanks, let me have a better think and a bit of coding test first following your suggestions